# How to display <ul> list like select box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, user-interface, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have some list, that I want perform to SE like ul list. But in GUI this data list better to perform like select box.

How I can display ul list like select box using jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `select` for each list, then insert it after and hide original one. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/XphEy/) and code:

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var ul=$(this);
    var sel=$('<select/>');
    $('li',ul).each(function(){
        sel.append($('<option/>',{value:this.innerHTML,html:this.innerHTML}));
    });
    ul.hide().after(sel);
});
```